# how do I display an image in a nested switch statement?

Tags: java, libgdx, perlin-noise

I am currently trying to make a game that involves a randomly generated world. I currently have a working splash screen and a working perlin noise gen with it normalized. all i need is a way to implement the code to display the images.

the code:

```
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    World world = new World();


    int type = 0;

    for (int y = 1; y < world.getlengthy();y++){
        for (int x = 1; x < world.getlengthx();x++){
        type = world.getvalue(x, y);


        switch (type) {
            case 1:sprite = new Sprite(tex1,0,0,16,16);sprite.setPosition(x, y);batch.begin();sprite.draw(batch);batch.end();
            Gdx.app.log("", "x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            break;
            case 2:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex2, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 3:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex3, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 4:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex4, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 5:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex5, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 6:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex6, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 7:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex7, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            case 8:batch.begin();batch.draw(tex8, x, y);batch.end();
            break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code need to be inside of the `render` method. The show is just called if the screen get shown the first time. (1 Time call!) So put the for loop inside of the render Cycle and it should work.

Just as a small hint. Do not create Objects inside of your render cycle `sprite = new Sprite(tex1,0,0,16,16);`. Always initialize all objects in the show method or inside of the constructor to save rendertime.(it does make a big differents in framerates)

Also just `begin()` one time befor the loop and `end()` after the loop.

For example something like this. I still wouldnt create Sprites inside of the render but i dont know the rest of your logic. Hope this helps! Regards

```
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    World world = new World();
}


@Override
public void render(float delta){
    int type = 0;
    batch.begin();
    for (int y = 1; y < world.getlengthy();y++){
        for (int x = 1; x < world.getlengthx();x++){
        type = world.getvalue(x, y);


        switch (type) {
            case 1:
                sprite = new Sprite(tex1,0,0,16,16);
                sprite.setPosition(x, y);
                sprite.draw(batch);
                Gdx.app.log("", "x: " + x + " y: " + y);
            break;
            case 2:
                batch.draw(tex2, x, y);
            break;
            case 3:
                batch.draw(tex3, x, y);
            break;
            case 4:
                batch.draw(tex4, x, y);
            break;
            case 5:
                batch.draw(tex5, x, y);
            break;
            case 6:
                batch.draw(tex6, x, y);
            break;
            case 7:
                batch.draw(tex7, x, y);
            break;
            case 8:
                batch.draw(tex8, x, y);
            break;
            }
        }
        batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. my code is not that optimized because i want to get a playable prototype before i make it optimized, I also realized that the render is like the game loop after this but thanks for the tip about the render loop.

Comment: Your wellcome. The render is actually the gameloop ;) the show should be some kinde of init.